# How to access widget configuration options in Block class?

Tags: magento2, blocks, widget, parameter

Although there's a similar [question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/314413/how-to-get-widget-parameter-data-in-code-block) asked, it doesn't have an answer as the comment there refers to a question which has a comment that shows how to access the admin panel configuration parameters in the template file which works fine for me (i.e. `$this->getData('config_param_name');`).

The issue is that the `$data` array injected in the Block class constructor is empty when inserting it via `Magento admin -> Content -> Widgets -> Add widget -> Layout update` while it has the Widget configuration options (`widget options` in admin panel) when the widget is inserted via `Content -> Page -> (select page) -> Insert widget` as tested via xdebug.

I need to check against the configuration options in the Block class and do conditional logic, so accessing the parameters from template file is too late in the call stack.

```
<?php

declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace Company\SomeWidget\Block\Widget;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Cms\Api\PageRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Api\SearchCriteriaBuilder;
use Magento\Widget\Block\BlockInterface;

class SomeWidgetBlock extends Template implements BlockInterface
{
    /** @var string  */
    protected $_template = 'Company_SomeWidget::template.phtml';

    protected $_param1;

    protected $_param2;

    /** @var PageRepositoryInterface */
    protected PageRepositoryInterface $_pageRepository;

    /** @var SearchCriteriaBuilder */
    protected SearchCriteriaBuilder $_searchBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context,
        PageRepositoryInterface $pageRepositoryInterface,
        SearchCriteriaBuilder $searchCriteriaBuilder,
        array $data = [] // <-- This is empty when widget is inserted via layout update
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);

        $this->_pageRepository = $pageRepositoryInterface;
        $this->_searchBuilder = $searchCriteriaBuilder;
        $this->_param1 = $this->getData('param_1');
        $this->_param2 = $this->getData('param_2');
    }
}
```